# add() argument after * must be an iterable, not int

Tags: python, pygame

İ am just start new to pygame and now i am still struggling for learn. İf anyone can contribute my studying i am realy be happy, because i am still can't find it. Here is my code:

```
import pygame

# window size
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
#FPS = 30 # how fast game is
```

Creating Bullet class

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite): 
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self, x, y )
        self.image = pygame.image.load('bullet.png').convert()
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )
        self.velocity    = 1

    def update( self ):
        x, y = self.rect.center    # get current position
        y -= self.velocity         # move up (negative-Y is up)
        if ( y < 0 ):
            self.kill()            # went off top of screen
        else:
            self.rect.center = ( x, y )
```

Creating Player class then call inside the update definition to bullet class

```
 class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # sprite for the player
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('warship.png').convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH/2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 50
        self.speedx = 0



    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -4
        elif keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 4
        elif keystate[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            # Create a new bullet just above the player
            global all_bullets_group
            x, y = self.rect.center
            new_bullet = Bullet( x, y-5 )
            all_bullets_group.add(new_bullet) 

        else:
            self.speedx = 0

        self.rect.x += self.speedx



        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0


    def getCoordinates(self):
        return (self.rect.x,self.rect.y)





# initialize pygame and create window
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
background = pygame.image.load('yeni_resim.jpg')
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invaders')
icon = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


# sprite
all_sprite = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprite.add(player)


# game loop
running = True
while running:  

    #clock.tick(FPS)
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))    
    all_sprite.update()
    all_sprite.draw(screen)


    # after drawing flip display
    pygame.display.flip()


    # process input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            break
```

after press run  and taking this error:

File "C:\Users\191119\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\191119\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/191119/Desktop/Pygame Projects/SpaceShip Game(My First Project)/Attending Artificial Intelligence(Reinforcement Learning)/Trying.py", line 105, in 
    all_sprite.update()

File "C:\Users\191119\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 463, in update
    s.update(*args)

File "C:/Users/191119/Desktop/Pygame Projects/SpaceShip Game(My First Project)/Attending Artificial Intelligence(Reinforcement Learning)/Trying.py", line 54, in update
    new_bullet = Bullet( x, y-5 )

File "C:/Users/191119/Desktop/Pygame Projects/SpaceShip Game(My First Project)/Attending Artificial Intelligence(Reinforcement Learning)/Trying.py", line 15, in **init**
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.**init**( self, x, y )

File "C:\Users\191119\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 124, in **init**
    self.add(*groups)

File "C:\Users\191119\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 142, in add
    self.add(*group)

TypeError: add() argument after * must be an iterable, not int

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: I think the question has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53804098/add-argument-after-must-be-an-iterable-not-int-pygame.

Comment: thx for interest for everyone. Forgive my inexperienced. Thanks so lot. I editted my question

Comment: You're passing `self,x,y` to the `pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__()`.  This should just be `self`.

Comment: when i do this then start run, this time i can't see bullet  :((((((((((